# What is the difference between featured songs and original songs?

Tags: genre

This article of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_recorded_by_Maroon_5) divided songs into **featured songs** and **original songs**.

What is the difference between featured songs and original songs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia article you link to is the [List of songs recorded by Maroon 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_recorded_by_Maroon_5#Featured_songs) and it has four tables:

**Original Songs** - Songs composed, recorded and released by Maroon 5.

**Covers** - Songs recorded and released by Maroon 5, which had been previously recorded and released by some other artist.

**Unreleased Songs** - Songs recorded by Maroon 5 but never released.

**Featured Songs** - Songs recorded and released by another artist, featuring one or more members of Maroon 5 (see the last column "Featured Member").

**Kara's Flowers** - Songs by the band Kara's Flowers, which is what these dudes were called before they became Maroon 5.